# Rollback all previous hibernate transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, rollback

I have two tables and I am using hibernate to save the data. I want to rollback transactions from all the tables if the last table gets some error during saving.

For example I have two tables naming Term and card acceptor and I am saving the data in them one by one. Below are the functions for both the tables:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Transaction tx = null;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
@Override
public TmCardAcceptor saveCardAcceptor(TmCardAcceptor cardAcceptor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Acquire session
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    // Save employee, saving behavior get done in a transactional manner
    //session.save(cardAcceptor); //previous method
    try {


        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(cardAcceptor); 
        tx.commit();


    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        try{
        tx.rollback();
    }catch(RuntimeException rbe){
    }
    throw e;
    } finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return cardAcceptor;        

}

@Override
public Term saveTerm(Term term) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Acquire session
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    // Save employee, saving behavior get done in a transactional manner
    //session.save(cardAcceptor); //previous method
    try {


        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(term); 
        tx.commit();


    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        try{
            System.out.println("Rolling back Term");
        tx.rollback();
    }catch(RuntimeException rbe){
    }
    throw e;
    } finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return term;        

}
```

If there is an error in Terms table this code does not roll back card acceptor.. Please help, how to achieve this...

Comment: Do you have 1 method that calls both methods?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes , both methods are being called from the same function of another class.

Comment: Then handle the transaction inside that method

Comment: ohk @XtremeBaumer so you mean I should rollback in that method instead?

Comment: Yes, you can only rollback transactions unless they have been `commited`. There is also transaction-nesting, but that can become quite complex, especially if you handle it manually. As you are using hibernate and spring, research `@Transactional`. It can make life much easier

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the transaction system.

A transaction is supposed to be [ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Once you have commit the transaction the change are done and you'll have to undo it manually. If you want the Term and CardAcceptor to be linked then you have to open only 1 transaction, save both objects and then commit it.

Comment: ohk so two different transactions can not be rolled back?

Comment: The rollback of Transaction 1 should not affect the result of Transaction 2, you work has to be atomic. In some cases, when you work on multiple sources (for example 2 differents DataSource of a DataSource and a JMS connection) you want Transaction 1 and 2 to commit or rollback at once. Then you have to use an external transaction manager and use [2 phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) capabilities. But it's not your case